# Number of vertices Peter

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Peter wants to paint the vertices of a $ 2 $   x $ n $ board so that every square on this board has exactly one painted vertex.

a) What is the maximum number of vertices Peter can paint?

b) What is the minimum number of vertices that Peter can paint?

Paint the upper left corner, skip two squares to the right paint the current one, repeat the process until finished -> maximum number

Same thing starting with the guy on the right hand side of the upper left corner -> minimum number

I don't know if I'm right, but if I am, can anyone formalize it?

Comment: a board had $4$ vertices only. Do you mean paint (some of) the vertices of the squares (of side length $1$) formed by a $2\times n$ grid? To be precise, say the board has vertices with coordinates $(0,0),(1,0),(2,0), (0,1),(1,1),(2,1),..(0,n),(1,n),(2,n)$. For the minimum try painting some of the vertices $(1,0),(1,1),..(1,n)$. For the maximum try painting some of the vertices $(0,0),(2,0), (0,1),(2,1),..(0,n),(2,n)$. Could you please describe what you have attempted (why would you suggest recursion) and whether my interpretation of what you are asking is correct?

Comment: I think I got it wrong, suggests recursion because of the amount of ways to do it

Comment: But that's the main idea

Comment: The problem is too easy if you only consider vertices of squares with side length $1$. Your description is not very clear to me (what does a "board" mean) and my comment above attempts to clarify it, but perhaps I am making the wrong assumptions. Are squares with side length $2$ allowed? (I guess no, as then there will be no legitimate painting.) Are squares with side length $\sqrt2$ allowed (and with sides $\pm45^\circ$ degrees from the horizontal, assuming the grid in my previous comment)? Is it a hint in a book that suggests recursion, or is this an idea you think might be relevant?

Comment: @Mirko I just thought this idea would be relevant, I can send the original problem to you if you want

Comment: is the original problem different? Does it specify what kind of squares could/should be used? If you confirm the types of squares, I may be able to post an answer. Is my interpretation above correct, as to what you are asking? If you could sent "the original problem", please do.

Comment: The original problem is identical to this one, but it is from a Brazilian Olympiad

Comment: Your idea is excellent, I'll see if I can find a solution ...

Comment: I know the solution, I just do not seem to be able to get a confirmation of what the problem is... :)

Comment: "a)What is the maximum number of vertices Peter can paint?

b) What is the minimum number of vertices that Peter can paint?"

Comment: With the information you have, find the minimum and maximum

Comment: Paint the upper left corner, skip two squares to the right paint the current one, repeat the process until finished -> maximum number.

Same thing starting with the guy on the right hand side of the upper left corner -> minimum number .

I don't know if I'm right, but if I am, can anyone formalize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I read the problem you want to paint exactly one of the lattice points of each square of a $3 \times (n+1)$ lattice.  For the maximum you want to paint points on the top and bottom rows, so do your start at the top left and paint every other one, then start at the bottom left and paint every other one.  For the minimum you want to paint points on the middle row, so start one in from the left and paint every other one.  The figure below shows the two solutions.  The circles are the painted points.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found floor \frac{n}{2} (minimum) and ceil \frac{n}{2} (maximum). But can we better formalize this?

Comment: You are off a factor $2$ for the maximum.  See my picture.  That is a fine formalization.

Comment: Thank you very much :)